# How can I sequence through a series of similar not-contained blocks in simple_html_dom

Tags: parsing, dom, block, simple-html-dom

I need to parse a large document that has elements arranged as a series of headings followed by a div, something like this:

```
<h2> Section Title </h2>
<div> Section Content</div>
<h2> Section Title 2</h2>
<div> Section Content2</div>
<h4> Section Title 3</h4>
<div> Section Content 3</div>
```

So basically in the dom, I need to group together an `<h>` with the next following `<div>`.   The dom doesn't seem to be an element for the child / sibling / parent functions, and I need to allow for inconsistencies in the input file as well so don't want to do something like find all the h elements, find all the divs, and walk through each list in a loop assuming the elements are the correct matches.  Is there any way to get the dom set up so I can walk through it using the child functions, or some other clean means of walking through the dom to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I figured out is to access the element 'root'to get to the top of the dom as an element.

From there it is still tricky to figure out how to walk through the sequence of child elements but in this case, search on the divs and prev_sibling() appears to work, if the content is predictable, but my content might be